# Autoscroll when div appears and when details/summary is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, display, autoscroll

I'm trying to figure out how to add autoscroll till the end of the page/div in 2 different situations as I'm new to JS.

1)When a div is appearing from display:none to block.

For example, here is when my alert appears and I want it to be fully shown. Is there a way to add in a piece of automatic code here? I made it mechanically so far.

```
    document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
        if(document.querySelector('select').value === "a") {
            rightAlert.style.display = 'block';
            wrongAlert.style.display = 'none';
            window.scrollBy(0, 100);
        }
```

2. When details/summary are clicked and expanded, with the traditional structure (Details, Summary, P)

Tried

```
document.querySelector('summary').onclick = function() {
                window.scrollBy(0, 100);
            };
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "to show the alert when switching from none to block"? Please, provide some more context. An option for this is using [CodePen](https://codepen.io/)

Comment: Hi @codeLearnerrr! I just mean there's a new div appearing on click, and I want the page to scroll till its end. So far I've added simply `window.scrollBy(0, 100);` as a 3rd line after if, but it's not automatic. And it also doesn't work for my second case - expanding the summary. Tried `document.querySelector('summary').onclick = function() {
                window.scrollBy(0, 100);
            };` but it didn't work as well. Do you know how to solve this with JS?

Comment: as codeLearnerrr saying, If you could prepare some example code which you could run codepen, it would be faster for us to grasp at what is going on with your code.

Comment: Also  window.scrollBy seems to be making the text slide towards left. but you want to have standard vertical scrolls, am I right ?

Comment: @AntiqTech no, window.scrollBy is not scrolling left. window.scrollBy(0, 100); is scrolling normally 100 px down. The thing is that I just want to scroll till the end of the division or page and not by set 100px.